# How to Customize Index name in ILM(index lifecycle management) of Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, ilm, index-management, elasticsearch-ilm

I am using ILM (Index Lifecycle Management) of Elastic to Index my live data(Email recieved).
The policy is created to rollover to new index on every 30 days.

The Index template is : WikiEmail-*.

So, Index is getting created every 30 days named as : WikiEmail-000001 and so forth.

Now I have an  requirement wherein I need to index historical data(Older Email from past few years).
How do I index the Older data in the monthly index fashion ?
IS there a way we can have cusotmied IndexName in ILM , so that the starting Index name is : WikiEmail-0000099.
In that case , I can index the older document by creating corresponding indices in the Warm Phase named as WikiEmail-0000098 ,WikiEmail-0000097 and likewise.

Answer (score 0):

you will run into issues here as the ILM policy will look at the index creation date when it comes to retention. so your old data may actually be around for longer than more recent data

if you want to have this data accessible under the ILM read alias, then you should index the data into whatever named indices you want, then attach them to that read alias

the only caveat is you will need to manage retention manually for those indices

Comment: Can we create Index manually onto the warm phase ? Will the manually created Indices  not follow the Policy of index migrating from warm phase to cold phase ?

Comment: they will but again based on the age of the index, not the data inside it